# Mirth Connect v. 3.1.1 - How to map variables from a url query string

Tags: url, mirth

I will take in a url encoded query string from customer:

string: ?siteId=13222&username=pvuser&password=PV01&externalId=942419444&firstName=John&lastName=Victor&gender=M&dob=11%2f10%2f1955&address=10100+FOREST+HILLS+RD&address2=SUITE+300&city=MACHESNEY+PARK&state=IL&zip=61115&homePhone=815-364-5761&cellPhone=815-818-0918&empName=AT%26T+UNITED+TECHNOLOGIES

I was instructed to use "Raw" as my data type however that doesn't give you a message tree to drag and drop.  Not being a programmer, this is hard to determine the best way to map the variables.

I found a simple JavaScript function, but I'm unable to parse through the data.  I'm missing the channelMap.put ('', ).  I'm not sure how that works.

```
var parseQueryString = function( queryString ) {
    var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;

    // Split into key/value pairs
    queries = queryString.split("&");

    // Convert the array of strings into an object
    for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }

    return params;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and use delimited text as your input type. You can set the delimiter to be the ampersand symbol. That would give you access to the message tree, which would allow you to use Mapper steps to store the values in the channel map (no need to worry about channelMap.put().

When you drag the values from the message template/tree into Mapper steps, if you'd like to strip out the part preceding and including the '=' (and this may look ugly/inefficient, but it sounds like you're not excited about javascript transformers), I'd add a substring call after the .toString that is put in by default. Each Mapper step's 'mapped value' would look something like this:

```
msg.value1.toString().substring(msg.value1.toString().indexOf('=') + 1);
```

That should give you only the value for each key in the querystring.

You can also do string replacement in mapper steps, allowing you to replace things like '%2f' with '/', and '+' with ' '. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you so much!  I did just that.  I used delimited text as my data type, but thought that couldn't be right because it is kind of ugly.  Then I used some regular expression string replacement for each node to retrieve just the value.  I'm sure there is a nicer way to do this, like javascript transformers (which you are right, I'm not excited by).  I'm going to try your suggestion of the mapper statment.  Thank you again so much!

Comment: Your suggestion was the better way.  It all works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry to leave you scratching your head for four full days :p